# How can I connect a PSP display to a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: display

So I recently took apart my old PSP 2000. I decided to keep my display from it to use for a Raspberry Pi project. I tried google but I couldn't really find anything. Does anybody know how to connect an LS043T3PX01 display on the Raspberry Pi B+?

Comment: Why do you think you can?

Comment: have you seen [this post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1664) over at raspberrypi.org? if not, I would suggest checking it out.

Comment: Some people already done it so i know it was possible. But none of them posted how they did it.

Comment: I did see that post but they only said it needs some soldering but it is possible. I searched for the datasheet of the screen but couldn't find really anything because there are two versions of my display, And mine has the back light control cable separated from the main cable.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100995/discussion-on-question-by-swiggolas-how-can-i-connect-a-psp-display-to-a-raspber).